NotificationCompat.Builder largeIcon does not fit

I am stuggling with setting of largeIcon in a notification
I found that the size of the large icon is 192x192 but the image i want to display is a pin icon with a size of (WxH) 174x290.
So...scale it is or so i thought.
I used the below code to scale my png keeping the W:H ratio.
    var bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.pin_bus)
    val largeIconHeight: Int = resources.getDimension(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_height).toInt()
    val largeIconWidth:  Int = (bitmap.width * (largeIconHeight.toFloat() / bitmap.height.toFloat())).toInt()
    val scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, largeIconWidth, largeIconHeight, false)

The result is the screen below.

Does anybody know how i can scale the bitmap to fit the largeicon while maintaining the W:H ratio?

Solved the issue.
Here is how i did it for others to benefit form
    // get the pin bitmap
    var bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.pin.bus)
    // scale the pin bitmap
    val largeIconHeight: Int = resources.getDimension(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_height).toInt()
    val largeIconWidth:  Int = (bitmap.width * (largeIconHeight.toFloat() / bitmap.height.toFloat())).toInt()
    val scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, largeIconWidth, largeIconHeight, false)
    // create a empty bitmap of the largeIcon size (192x192)
    val placeHolderBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(192, 192, Config.ARGB_8888)
    // place the scaled pin bitmap on the placeholder.
    val canvas: Canvas = Canvas(placeHolderBitmap)
    val left = (placeHolderBitmap.width - scaledBitmap.width) / 2
    val top  = (placeHolderBitmap.height - scaledBitmap.height) / 2
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBitmap,left.toFloat(),top.toFloat(),null)


After this i used the "placeHolderBitmap" as the largeIcon for the notification screen.
Result:
[![screen][1]][1]
